# Python re.findall Not Matching JS Variables in HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to extract integers and variable values defined in JavaScript in an HTML file using Python 3 `re.findall` method.

However, I am having a little difficulty matching digits enclosed in `"` with `\d*`, and matching an alphanumeric string enclosed in `"` too.

**Case 1:**

```
s = """
   <script>
    var i = 1636592595;
        var j = i + Number("6876" + "52907");
   </script>
"""
pattern = r'var j = i + Number(\"(\d*)\" + \"(\d*)\");'
m = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(m) # Output: []
```

The desired output should contain `6876` and `52907`, but an empty list `[]` was obtained.

**Case 2:**

```
s = """
       xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
              "bm-foo": "AAQAAAAE/////4ytkgqq/oWI",
              "pow": j
          }));
"""
pattern = r'"bm-foo": \"(\w*)\",'
m = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(m) # Output: []
```

The desired output should contain `AAQAAAAE/////4ytkgqq/oWI`, but an empty list `[]` was obtained.

Can I have some help explaining why my regex patterns are not matching it?

Comment: You need to escape the `+` characters. you don't need to escape `"`

Comment: You also need to escape the literal `(` characters.

Comment: `\w` only matches letters, numbers and `_`. So it won't match the `////` in the the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first regexp you need to escape `+`, `(`, and `)`.

In the second regexp, use `[^"]*` instead of `\w*`, since `\w` doesn't match punctuation like `/`.

```
import re

s = """
   <script>
    var i = 1636592595;
        var j = i + Number("6876" + "52907");
   </script>
"""
pattern = r'var j = i \+ Number\("(\d*)" \+ \"(\d*)\"\);'
m = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(m)

s = """
       xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
              "bm-foo": "AAQAAAAE/////4ytkgqq/oWI",
              "pow": j
          }));
"""
pattern = r'"bm-foo": "([^"]*)",'
m = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(m)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/n6k1ZV)